# JSON error even if PHP script works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

My JavaScript always returns an error, even if PHP did what it should.

No matter if I write `dataType: "JSON"` or `"JSONP"` or delete it completely.

When I remove `echo json_encode(...` it works as it should. I see the alert for success.

But I want to make two or three success messages appear in-line in html.

Here is my JS code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#przypinanie').click(function() {
    var data_cat = $('select#cat').val();
    var data_post_id = $('input#przypinanie-post-id').val() ;
    var przypinanie = $('input#przypinanie').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            cat_id: data_cat, 
            post_id: data_post_id,
            przypinanie_usuwanie: przypinanie,
            action: "przypinanie_php"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
    });
});
```

My PHP code:

```
if ( $przypinanie == "PRZYPNIJ" ) {
    $validate = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT przypieta_cat_id FROM polecane_przypinane WHERE przypiety_post_id = '$post_id'");
    if ( isset($validate) ){    
        $msg = 'Wpis jest już przypięty do kategorii '. $validate ; 
    }else{
        $wpdb->insert( 'polecane_przypinane', 
            array(
            'przypiety_post_id' => $post_id,
            'przypieta_cat_id' => $cat_id,
            )
        );  
        $msg = 'Wpis został przypięty do kategorii '. $validate ;   
    }
    $responce = $msg;
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($responce);
```

Comment: if `$responce` is a string then why would you want to use `json_encode`?

Comment: *"Js always return error"* - What is the error message?

Comment: Also $response will be undefined if `$przypinanie` doesn't equal `"PRZYPNIJ"`

Comment: A possible reason to json_encode a plain string output ... is so that any multi-byte characters are handled better in javascript, as well as escaping of certain quote characters. *shrug* ... but he is just doing alert() so eh.

Comment: Thank you for forcing me to think :)

Answer (score -1):

OK. Thank You for answers.

I resigned from JSON and I just did `echo $responce;` at the end of function.

Pleased to solwed my first question here.